# How to get cumulative sum with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, cumulative-sum

Here is desire output :
[image]

I want to cum_sum the STEPID value (0-99). BUT, there are two pattern as can see from pic above.

Set LEFT : will multiply*1000 when STEPID is 14. And will continue with cum_sum until STEPID is 99.
Set RIGHT : normal cumulative sum until STEPID 99.

Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/06e4c/1

Answer (score 0):

If this is a SQL question then you can use a CASE syntax in your Query.  Here is an example of the method:

```
Select Sum(Case when X < Y Then A when X=Y then B Else C end) From Table
```

This allows you to add up the values only when you think that they apply.  You can also so math in the output as well.

```
Select Sum(Case when X <= Y Then A Else B*1000 end) From Table
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Hi @middletone. Thanks for replying. BTW, I don't think it is simple as that. Bcos the value is also depending on previous cumulative value(LAG()). Can refer my example on fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/06e4c/22. BUT, I cannot use this for both situation.